# NSDictionary Key For Value/Object?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nsdictionary

Can we get the key for an object in an `NSDictionary` by passing a particular value or object?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

[`-[NSDictionary allKeysForObject:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-BABDIABF) returns an `NSArray` of all the keys whose objects match the passed object, where "match" is determined by `isEqual:`.

Comment: but remember: it gives all keys for objects matching 'isEqual' not '=='

Comment: @Kai: True. I should perhaps also add a note about it returning an `NSArray` although that should be clear from the method name.

Comment: If this isn't an FGITW question and answer, I don't know what is. Five upvotes just because I have a search shortcut in my browser.

Answer (score 44):

To answer you question in a more specific manner, use the following to get a key for a particular object:

```
NSString *knownObject = @"the object";
NSArray *temp = [dict allKeysForObject:knownObject];
NSString *key = [temp lastObject];

//"key" is now equal to the key of the object you were looking for
```

Comment: In the case the object is not a string, replace NSString with the object class. This is self explanatory.

Comment: You might prefer `lastObject` to `objectAtIndex:0` to avoid throwing an exception if there are no such keys.

Comment: Or even `firstObject` if you are using the latest SDK

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can get a first key for object (in case it is an `NSString`):

```
NSArray *keys = [yourDic allKeysForObject:yourObject];
NSString *yourKey;
if ([keys count] > 0) {
   yourKey = keys[0];
}
```

This handles if the object is not found in in the dictionary.