# IOS: catch an information in a NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an NSArray and in the first position in this array there is a NSDictionary.
In this dictionary there is two values: first value have a key "name" and second value have a key "number".
If I know value of "name" can I get value of "number"?

Comment: do you have two key-value pairs?

Comment: i show an example: 
I have an array, inside this array there are four array.
In first of these four array there are 50 dictionary.
I want to know what is the dictionary with key "number" = 3, but I don't know dictionary index.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSDictionary Key For Value/Object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120926/nsdictionary-key-for-value-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in this way:

```
for (int j = 0; j<array.count; j++)
                {
                    NSArray *listaDictionary = [array objectAtIndex:j];

                    for(int x=0;x<listaDictionary.count;x++)
                    {
                        if([[[listaDictionary objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"number"]intValue] == myNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you're looking to find the key in a dictionary when you only know the value.

For example, you have a dictionary where "a" => "4" and "b" => "3", the following code:

```
NSArray* matchingKeys = [dictionary allKeysForObject:@"3"];
```

Would return an array with "b" as the only element.

Comment: no you don't understand, I want to check a dictionary but I don't know dictionary index but only the value of a key.

Comment: @blackguardian I don't think your question is very clear, but I have rewritten my answer.