# how to get key of selected value from nsdictionary

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsdictionary

I am using `NSDictionary` to get data from json and then i added the value from `NSDictionary` to `UITableView`.When user is selected one of the table cell it will send back the value.The point is how to get the key of selected value from table cell in `NSDictionary` in Swift?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var myFruits = ["0_22":"Sunkist","34_22":"Pine Apple","45_22":"Grape","1_123":"Apple"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // If my selected key is "Sunkist, what do i need to to get its value (0_22)"
    // Any Code Help?
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: posting some code would help

Comment: This question has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120926/nsdictionary-key-for-value-object

Comment: This page maybe answer for your question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120926/nsdictionary-key-for-value-object

Comment: I think you are not new in SO. Please always add `code` as like syntax.

Comment: Umm,i dont know anything about Objc Syntax.Is there any information about that i can get in Swift?

Comment: I am sorry that i update the code simple and small,but u can see my problem at comment.Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure if that really helps you, but Swift implementation "allKeysForObject" are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27218669/swift-dictionary-get-key-for-value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will work fine.

```
    var myFruits = ["0_22":"Sunkist","34_22":"Pine Apple","45_22":"Grape","1_123":"Apple"]

    var dic:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(dictionary:myFruits)
    println(dic.allKeysForObject("Sunkist"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for @Martin R who give me that answer.I got this now with that code

```
let keys = (myFruits as NSDictionary).allKeysForObject("Sunkist")
println(String(keys[0] as! NSString))
```

Output is

```
0_22
```